# Can we connect to active directory from apache LDAP API?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, apacheds

New here in LDAP learning. Sorry if it is duplicate question. It will be great if you can provide some links on this regards.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) is a software protocol for enabling anyone to locate organizations, individuals, and other resources such as files and devices in a network, whether on the public Internet or on a corporate intranet. For example I am using this protocol for connection between my active directory users and qradar siem program.

There are many programs which are using LDAP configuration. Therefore the configuration may change due to program. However for understanding its purporse you can follow these links.

https://www.ldap.com/basic-ldap-concepts
[What is LDAP used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239385/what-is-ldap-used-for)
https://www.techopedia.com/definition/2439/lightweight-directory-access-protocol-ldap