# what is difference between the LDAP VS Oauth 2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, ldap

What's the difference between LDAP and Oauth2? Which one is easier to use and to understand?

Comment: OAuth2 is simple, with OIDC Providers you get Implementation to use there login for your app (delegation)

Answer (score 8):

LDAP is a protocol to access directories. You can use it, for example, to access user information for authorization before granting user access to certain resources or data.
Check the answer here to understand LDAP better: [What is LDAP used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239385/what-is-ldap-used-for?rq=1) .

If you have LDAP implemented, you can add OAuth 2 to give a user (or application), access to your resources (depending on the rules in the LDAP directory) and provide her with a token that must be sent by the user on each request.

Know that you can also use one without the other.